# MySQL: How to get maximum value from a group with a condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table :

my_table:

```
hash version  active_flag
aaa  10.0     0 
bbb  11.1     0 
bbb  11.2     1 
ccc  12.1     0
ccc  12.2     0
ccc  12.3     0
```

How do I get maximum version number from same hash group and 'active_flag = 0'
The result should exclude.. those entries which have other version and active_flag=1 for the same hash.. In my table, it should exclude the row:

```
 hash version  active_flag 
  bbb   11.1   0
```

Sorry to all who down voted me!! Actually, I missed out a condition, included now!!!

Please help!!..

Comment: Read about GROUP BY and aggregate functions

Comment: no try or work by yourself ?

Comment: Sorry guys!! missed out a condition!!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT hash,MAX(version) 
FROM my_table
WHERE active_flag = 0
GROUP BY hash
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select hash,max(version) from table where active_flag=0 group by hash
```